# Is Tony Stark exaggerating about the potential espionage threat in the Marvel Universe?

Tags: marvel, iron-man, espionage

#### Specialized Espionage Services

While Tony is on a meet and greet using his smoothest moves on a world-class biological engineering genius, Dr. Amara Perera, who figured out, in an afternoon, how to safely erase the mutant gene from the Human Race... (Let that digest for a second.)

He reminds her the life of an industrialist or scientist in the Marvel Universe is fraught with espionage perils. Think I'm joking? Let Tony explain to you that NOT writing down your ideas doesn't make them safe...

[image]

*From Invincible Iron Man #1 (2015)*

**The question is: Are there such extreme specialized espionage services available in the Marvel Universe, who provides them, and are there any previously known examples of--**

- Psychic spies
- Psychic, industrial spies
- Psychic mutant spies
- Psychic, mutant, industrial spies

They don't need long dossiers, just a few sentences and maybe a link if they actually have something written on a wiki somewhere.

**Update to clarify:**

- I am not looking for people who engaged in a one-time use of their psychic powers, under coercion to gain information. As I already know the Marvel Universe is rife with potential psychics who might be coerced.
- I am looking for long-term, lifestyle-preferred, industrial spies. People who make a living stealing secrets, in this case preferably using psychic, mental, magically psychic or mutant means.
- These powers and abilities can come from any kind of origin, as long as psychic powers are used in some fashion. The person could use magic to gain their psychic ability, thus they would not necessarily need to be a mutant. They could have unexplained psychic powers (like the Shadow - the power to cloud men's minds) and still qualify.
- If they could use their magic for clairvoyance, they would not need to even be physically present to be capable of spying. The question is about are there people who use psychic abilities whether they be using mental powers, mutant powers, or magical powers to perform espionage. Have we seen it? Do we already know about them..

Comment: Shield has "psychic agents"; http://marvel.com/universe/Hill,_Maria

Comment: Sexy spy [Sage](http://comicvine.gamespot.com/sage/4005-4559/) seems to be a psychic gun-for-hire.

Comment: Yeah, so much that psychic agents were used to extract informations about House of M from Spider Man

Answer (score 7):

I was able to find examples of two of the ones you asked for. I'm still looking for the others.

**- Psychic spies:**

> The Psi-Division of S.H.I.E.L.D. is a group of psychics or telepaths that deal with psionic menaces. [Source](http://comicvine.gamespot.com/shield/4060-3775/)

[Here](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Category:S.H.I.E.L.D._Psi_Division_members)'s a list of members.

**- Psychic mutant spies**

Several of the pre-mentioned Psi-Division members, most notably [Psylocke](http://marvel.com/characters/42/psylocke).

---

I was unable to find any psychic industrial spies, mutant or otherwise. While industrial spies [do](http://marvel.com/universe/Spymaster_(spy)) [exist](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Actor_(Earth-616)) in the 616 universe, none seem to have any superpowers.

Whether Tony was wrong or exaggerating or we just haven't encountered any yet remains to be seen.